# Query Connections finish before executing code

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a series of connections I want to finish refreshing before the code immediately after that executes. I've tried turning background refreshing off for all, but that makes each one refresh individually, which takes too long. Ideally, I want all the connections executed at once and then once all have finished, the code after executes. I've listed each one as there are other queries in the workbook that I don't want refreshed. These queries are connected to an OData Feed connection. I've looked at other solutions but they are normally only refreshing one query or all the queries in their workbook.

At present this is what the refresh looks like in VBA

```
With ThisWorkbook
.Connections("Query - #1").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #2").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #3").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #4").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #5").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #6").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #7").Refresh
.Connections("Query - #8").Refresh
End With
```

Comment: Maybe look here: https://www.excelandaccess.com/create-beforeafter-query-update-events/

Answer (score 0):

insert a

```
DoEvents
```

after the last refresh you need.